# Null Pointer Exception in Robotium All in package test

Tags: android, robotium, android-testing

I can run and pass all of my tests but when I want to run all of test (setup as following image), I get this error:

```
**Test running failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.NullPointerException'**
setting:
```

[image]

I am using robotium-solo:5.4.1

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined `testInstrumentationRunner`, check this site: https://guides.codepath.com/android/UI-Testing-with-Robotium